# parsing file with curley brakets

Tags: python, parsing, pyparsing

I need to parse a file with information separated by curly brackets, for example:

```
Continent
{
Name    Europe
Country
{
Name    UK
Dog
{
Name    Fiffi
Colour  Gray
}
Dog
{
Name    Smut
Colour  Black
}
}
}
```

Here is what I have tried in Python

```
from io import open
from pyparsing import *
import pprint

def parse(s):
    return nestedExpr('{','}').parseString(s).asList()

def test(strng):
    print strng
    try:
        cfgFile = file(strng)
        cfgData = "".join( cfgFile.readlines() )
        list = parse( cfgData )
        pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(2)
        pp.pprint(list)

    except ParseException, err:
        print err.line
        print " "*(err.column-1) + "^"
        print err

    cfgFile.close()
    print
    return list

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test('testfile')
```

But this fails with an error:

```
testfile
Continent
^
Expected "{" (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xxx.py", line 55, in <module>
    test('testfile')
  File "xxx.py", line 40, in test
    return list
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'list' referenced before assignment
```

What do I need to do to make this work?
Is another parser than pyparsing better?

Comment: off topic but it is better to not use `list` as variable name as it is reserved in python

Comment: I can propose You solution with recursion based algorithm. Does it fit your requirements (split whole data by '{' once and rsplit by '}' once. outer part should be parsed as key-value for returned dictionary and inner part should be passed to recursive function itself. and so on...)

Comment: Please show what would like as result.

Comment: Why down-voting the question? It requires maybe some extra information such as the expected output ... but interesting nevertheless ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Recursivity* is the key here. Try something around that:

```
def parse(it):
    result = []
    while True:
        try:
            tk = next(it)
        except StopIteration:
            break

        if tk == '}':
            break
        val = next(it)
        if val == '{':
            result.append((tk,parse(it)))
        else:
            result.append((tk, val))

    return result
```

The use case:

```
import pprint       

data = """
Continent
{
Name    Europe
Country
{
Name    UK
Dog
{
Name    Fiffi
Colour  Gray
}
Dog
{
Name    Smut
Colour  Black
}
}
}
"""

r = parse(iter(data.split()))
pprint.pprint(r)
```

... which produce (Python 2.6):

```
[('Continent',
  [('Name', 'Europe'),
   ('Country',
    [('Name', 'UK'),
     ('Dog', [('Name', 'Fiffi'), ('Colour', 'Gray')]),
     ('Dog', [('Name', 'Smut'), ('Colour', 'Black')])])])]
```

Please take this as only  starting point, and feel free to improve the code as you need (depending on your data, a dictionary could have been a better choice, maybe). In addition, the sample code does not handle properly ill formed data (notably extra or missing `}` -- I urge you to do a full test coverage ;)

---

**EDIT:** Discovering `pyparsing`, I tried the following which appears to work (much) better and could be (more) easily tailored for special needs:

```
import pprint
from pyparsing import Word, Literal, Forward, Group, ZeroOrMore, alphas

def syntax():
    lbr = Literal( '{' ).suppress()
    rbr = Literal( '}' ).suppress()
    key = Word( alphas )
    atom = Word ( alphas )
    expr = Forward()
    pair = atom | (lbr + ZeroOrMore( expr ) + rbr)
    expr << Group ( key + pair )

    return expr

expr = syntax()
result = expr.parseString(data).asList()
pprint.pprint(result)
```

Producing:

```
[['Continent',
  ['Name', 'Europe'],
  ['Country',
   ['Name', 'UK'],
   ['Dog', ['Name', 'Fiffi'], ['Colour', 'Gray']],
   ['Dog', ['Name', 'Smut'], ['Colour', 'Black']]]]]
```

Comment: Using `split()` to break up tokens works for this sample data, but not all inputs may be so nicely formatted. `split()` will fail if the trailing braces are entered as "}}}", for instance, or if any entry contains braces inside a quoted string.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire that is correct. The initial question does not specify entirely the format of input data. Regarding white-spaces around curly braces -- a regexp would do the trick. If the grammar is more complex, for instance as you said, containing quoted stings -- `pyparsing` still would be a better bet.

Comment: Nice work, this is a more rigorous parser than just using nestedExpr, you retain the key+value relationships. Welcome to pyparsing, Sylvain!

Answer (score 5):

Nested expressions are so common, and usually require recursive parser definitions or recursive code if you're not using a parsing library. This code can be daunting for beginners, and error prone even for experts, so that is why I added the `nestedExpr` helper to pyparsing.

The problem you are having is that your input string has more than just a nested braces expression in it. When I am first trying out a parser, I try to keep the testing as simple as possible - i.e., I inline the sample instead of reading it from a file, for instance.

```
test = """\
Continent
{
Name    Europe
Country
{
Name    UK
Dog
{
Name    Fiffi
Colour  "light Gray"
}
Dog
{
Name    Smut
Colour  Black
}}}"""

from pyparsing import *

expr = nestedExpr('{','}')

print expr.parseString(test).asList()
```

And I get the same parsing error that you do:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nb.py", line 25, in <module>
    print expr.parseString(test).asList()
  File "c:\python26\lib\site-packages\pyparsing-1.5.7-py2.6.egg\pyparsing.py", line 1006, in parseString
    raise exc
pyparsing.ParseException: Expected "{" (at char 1), (line:1, col:1)
```

So looking at the error message (and even at your own debugging code), pyparsing is stumbling on the leading word "Continent", because this word is not the beginning of a nested expression in braces, pyparsing (as we see in the exception message) was looking for an opening '{'.

The solution is to slightly modify your parser to handle the introductory "Continent" label, by changing expr to:

```
expr = Word(alphas) + nestedExpr('{','}')
```

Now, printing out the results as a list (using pprint as done in the OP, nice work) looks like:

```
['Continent',
 ['Name',
  'Europe',
  'Country',
  ['Name',
   'UK',
   'Dog',
   ['Name', 'Fiffi', 'Colour', '"light Gray"'],
   'Dog',
   ['Name', 'Smut', 'Colour', 'Black']]]]
```

which should match up with your brace nesting.

Comment: I discovered pyparsing thanks to this question -- not much documentation online, but very interesting module indeed. Is there a way to produce a dictionary instead of nested lists?