# Parsing named nested expressions with pyparsing

Tags: python, pyparsing

I'm trying to parse some data using pyparsing that looks (more or less) like this:

```
User.Name = Dave
User.Age  = 42
Date      = 2015/01/01
Begin Component List
  Begin Component 2
    1 some data   = a value
    2 another key = 999
  End Component 2
  Begin Another Component
    a.key = 42
  End Another Component
End Component List
Begin MoreData
    Another = KeyPair
End MoreData
```

I've found some similar examples, but I've not done very well for myself.

[parsing file with curley brakets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16958087/parsing-file-with-curley-brakets)
[Parse line data until keyword with pyparsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28731655/parse-line-data-until-keyword-with-pyparsing)

Here's what I have so far, but I keep hitting an error similar to: `pyparsing.ParseException: Expected "End" (at char 26), (line:5, col:1)`

```
from pyparsing import *

data = '''Begin A
hello
world
End A
'''

opener = Literal('Begin') + Word(alphas)
closer = Literal('End') + Word(alphas)
content = Combine(OneOrMore(~opener
                            + ~closer
                            + CharsNotIn('\n', exact=1)))
expr = nestedExpr(opener=opener, closer=closer, content=content)

parser = expr

res = parser.parseString(data)
print(res)
```

It's important the the words after "Begin" are captured, as these are the names of the dictionaries, as well as the key-value pairs. Where there is a number after the opener, e.g. "Begin Component 2" the "2" is the number of pairs which I don't need (presumably this is used by the original software?). Similarly, I don't need the numbers in the list (the "1" and "2").

Is `nestedExpr` the correct approach to this?